# Getting two different lat/long for same location in OSM world map

Tags: google-maps, gis, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am working on Openlayers 4 with OSM map.

1. When I zoomed out the map then I found the 4-5 map in small size. I want only one map.
2. When I am dropping the custom marker same country same location then I found the different-2 lat log in other small size map.
3. So how can I get the same lat long for all world map?
4. As I am adding marker in Australia and from one Australia to another it's changing different lat long for same location.
5. I am using Openlayers as client api, I want to know how to get lat long same for all same location.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's called wrapping. It's so the map functions like a globe.

Do

```
 new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM({
    wrapX: false
  })
})
```